# go program throwing error cannot find package "code.google.com/p/go.net/websocket"

Tags: go

I am new to Go programming language. Below is my code.

```
package main

import (
    "code.google.com/p/go.net/websocket"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"
)

var add := "12345"

func EchoLengthServer(ws *webscoket.Conn) {
    var msg string

    for {
        websocket.Message.Receive(ws, &msg)
        fmt.Println("Got Message", msg)
        length := len(msg)
        if err := websocket.Message.Send(ws, strconv.FormatInt(int64(length), 10)); err != nil {
            fmt.Println("can't send message length")
            break
        }
    }
}

func websocketListen() {
    http.Handle("/length", websocket.Handler(EchoLengthServer))
    err := http.ListenAndServe(addr, nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic("ListenAndServe:" + err.Error())
    }
}
```

when I executed  the code i got below error

```
[rajkumar@localhost ch4-DesigningAPI]$ go run WebSockets.go 
WebSockets.go:6:3: cannot find package "code.google.com/p/go.net/websocket" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/code.google.com/p/go.net/websocket (from $GOROOT)
    /home/rajkumar/GOPackages/src/code.google.com/p/go.net/websocket (from $GOPATH)
```

I tried to add websocket package in GOPATH by go get command but that is also throwing below error

```
[rajkumar@localhost ch4-DesigningAPI]$ go get code.google.com/p/go.net/websocket
go: missing Mercurial command. See http://golang.org/s/gogetcmd
package code.google.com/p/go.net/websocket: exec: "hg": executable file not found in $PATH
```

Could you please help me in resolving this error.

Comment: Just install Mercurial. This has nothing to do with Go.

Comment: @Volker: [`golang.org/x/net/websocket`](http://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/websocket) is [Git](https://git-scm.com/). `code.google.com/p/go.net/websocket` is obsolete: [Bidding farewell to Google Code](http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2015/03/farewell-to-google-code.html).

Comment: @Peter Yes, but importing the old one (for whatever reasons) requires Mercurial. Btw: I upvoted your answer.

Comment: Thanks Volker and Peter. This command is working magically. Thanks for yor help.

Comment: Below is the function main

Answer (score 15, accepted):

How about this?

```
$ go get -v golang.org/x/net/websocket
golang.org/x/net/websocket
$
```

-

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"

    "golang.org/x/net/websocket"
)

var addr = "12345"

func EchoLengthServer(ws *websocket.Conn) {
    var msg string

    for {
        websocket.Message.Receive(ws, &msg)
        fmt.Println("Got Message", msg)
        length := len(msg)
        if err := websocket.Message.Send(ws, strconv.FormatInt(int64(length), 10)); err != nil {
            fmt.Println("can't send message length")
            break
        }
    }
}

func websocketListen() {
    http.Handle("/length", websocket.Handler(EchoLengthServer))
    err := http.ListenAndServe(addr, nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic("ListenAndServe:" + err.Error())
    }
}

func main() {}
```